# JavaScript - Find a word string out of strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to find a word from consecutive strings inside an array and I am stuck at the moment.

For example: `array = ['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'];` I want to make a function that will return true if the word 'apple' is inside this array. Strings need to be consecutive.

`array1 = ['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'l', 'p', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'];` function for this kind of strings with no consecutive 'apple' strings should return false.

Can you help please?

Comment: If you're allowed to use built-ins, `join + includes` should do the trick

Comment: Seems to me that this is a problem solvable using the sliding window algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
array = ["w", "r", "a", "p", "p", "l", "e", "f", "k", "l"];

console.log(array.toString().replace(/,/g,"").indexOf("apple")>-1);
```

Comment: I didn't, that was someone else. I up voted to balance it since your solution works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be traverse your array, and get substrings of length that equals the length of the matching substring, and compare the substring with the matching substring

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length-matching.length; i++) {
    if (array.substr(i, i+matching.length) == matching) return true;
} return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var array = ['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'];

function findWord(arr, word) {
  return arr.join('').indexOf(word) !== -1;
}

// test
console.log('apple: ', findWord(array, 'apple'))
console.log('dog: ', findWord(array, 'dog'))
```

Answer (score 0):

check this function:

```
function hasWord(inputSourceList, inputWord) {
    return inputSourceList.join('').indexOf(inputWord) > -1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.join()`, `String.replace()` and `String.indexOf()` functions:

```js
var contains_word = function(arr, w) {
    return arr.join('').replace(new RegExp('[^' + w + ']', 'g'), '')
           .indexOf(w) !== -1; 
}

console.log(contains_word(['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'l', 'p', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'], 'apple'));
console.log(contains_word(['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'], 'apple'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if all letters are found in the correct order:

```js
const findWordInArray = (word, array) => {
  let last = -1; // stores the last index found
  
  // iterate the letters of the word
  return [...word].every((c) => {
    // search for the letter from the last known position + 1 onwards
    const index = array.indexOf(c, last + 1);
    last = index; // change last to the new found position
    return index !== -1;
  });
}

const array1 = ['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'];
const array2 = ['w', 'r', 'a', 'p', 'l', 'p', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l'];
const word = 'apple';

console.log(findWordInArray(word, array1));
console.log(findWordInArray(word, array2));
```